# How should I name my namespaces in PHP correctly?

Tags: php, namespaces

I'm developing classes in PHP. For naming I followed the PSR-4 Autoloader rules:

https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/

But somehow I'm confused. So for example if I have this class in the following structure, how should I define the namespace?

**The path of the file:**

```
wmx/includes/classes/admin/Wmx_Settings.php
```

**The class name:**

```
class Wmx_Settings {....
```

**My thoughts about namespaces:**

```
namespace Johnny\Wmx\Admin\;
namespace Johnny\Wmx\Admin\Wmx_Settings;
```

So how should I define my namespaces now? I'm not very clear about that. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
namespace Johnny\Wmx\Admin;
...
class Wmx_Settings {....
```

Answer (score -1):

```
namespace MyNamespaceName; 
    
require 'project/database/connection.php'; 
    
use Project\Database\Connection as Connection; 
    
$connection = new Connection(); 
    
use Project\Database as Database; 
    
$connection = new Database\Connection();
```

Comment: That was not the question sir. Sorry :/

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.

Comment: You should read the question properly before replying.